# Production database tables not being created

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using ASP.NET EntityFramework **Core**

My production environment database is not having tables created inside it.

As per this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/29/implementing-seeding-custom-conventions-and-interceptors-in-ef-core-1-0/

I have added this code to my `Startup.Configure()` method:

```
using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
{
       var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyContext>();       
       context.Database.Migrate();
 }
```

This does not work.  I am given no error message, there is just no tables created. (locally in development encironment I created them with `update-database`)

I am trying this on my production server.  The process I followed was to publish site and then upload the PublishOutput folder to the server.  The app works fine everywhere it doesn't require the database.

Does the published website contain the migrations?

How do I carry out the migrations on my production database?

Again, please note I am using the **Core** version.  Answers relating to older versions of entity framework do not apply.

Answer (score 0):

It works if I manually create the `__EFMigrationsHistory` table

```
CREATE TABLE `__EFMigrationsHistory` (
  `MigrationId` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `ProductVersion` varchar(32) NOT NULL
)
```